# Re-number the id's of table rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, attr

I have the following table code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-id='1' id='item-1'>
        <td>30-01-2014</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr data-id='19' id='item-2'>
        <td>30-01-2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id='5' id='item-3'>
        <td>30-01-2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id='39' id='item-4'>
        <td>30-01-2014</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('table tbody').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updatePagesOrder.php'
        });
    }
});
var i = 1;
$('table > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    $('tr').attr('id', 'item-' + i);
    i++;
});
```

What I want to do is that after the `sortable` function executed the id of the items will be ordered again from 1 to 4.
I have tried to code above, but it didn't work.

Wish for help...Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to declare `i` you're already using  [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) So

try this

```
$('table > tbody tr').each(function (i) {
     $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + (i + 1)); // use $(this) as a reference to current tr object
});
```

used `(i+1)` because index starts from `0`

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9zcb/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('tr')` inside the `.each()` loop, use `$(this)`:

```
$('table > tbody tr').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it doesn't work... (the id is not updated at all)

Comment: You also need to remove `>` after `tbody` in your selector like above i did

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question very well, but I believe you want the IDs to update whenever the table rows are reordered?

If that's the case, then I believe the issue is that you are updating the IDs after initializing the sortable plugin, but this change will be overridden when the user reorders the table rows. What you should instead do is update the IDs in the update function. If you want the IDs to be updated after serialization, then place the call to updateRowIDs() after the call to the serialization.

```
$('table tbody').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        updateRowIDs();
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updatePagesOrder.php'
        });
    }
});

function updateRowIDs()
{
    var i = 1;
    $('table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        this.id = 'item-' + i;
        i++;
    });
}
```